# pandas select rows and cell values based on column and other conditions

Tags: pandas, row

How to do the following in pandas-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ColA': [1, 2, 3, 11111, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'ColB': [11, 5, 22, 66, 4, 33333, 45, 91, 78, 10, 17, 55, 73, 85, 56, 99, 4, 74],
    'ColC': ['A', 'B', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    'ColD': [0,0,0,0,0, 22222,0,0,0,0,0,48,0,0,52,0,0,0]
})
```

Disregard all rows before 1st and after last occurrence of X in ColC

search for 1st occurrence of X in ColC, select one row below, take value (say, Y) from ColA from such selected row. (in df it is 11111)

search for 2nd occurrence of X in ColC, take value (say, Z) from ColB from such row. (in df it is 33333)

write result value (Z-Y) in ColD next to 2nd occurrence of X. (should be 33333-11111 = 22222)

Repeat for pairs of 2nd and 3rd occurrence of X, 3rd and 4th, 4th and 5th and so on till the end of df.

Expected result in ColD.

Comment: what would be the exact expected output?

Comment: edited df, now it shows expected result in ColD

Comment: OK, so I got it right? ;) you can add a `reindex(df.index).fillna(0)` to get the 0s if needed

Comment: @mozway you were right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)-fu and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['ColC'].eq('X')

df['ColD'] = df.loc[m, 'ColB'] - df['ColA'].shift(-1)[m].shift()
```

Or, if you want 0s:

```
m = df['ColC'].eq('X')

df['ColD'] = (df['ColB'].sub(df['ColA'].shift(-1)[m].shift())
                .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
             )
```

Output:

```
     ColA   ColB ColC   ColD
0       1     11    A      0
1       2      5    B      0
2       3     22    X      0
3   11111     66    C      0
4       5      4    D      0
5       6  33333    X  22222
6       7     45    E      0
7       8     91    F      0
8       9     78    G      0
9       1     10    A      0
10      2     17    B      0
11      3     55    X     48
12      4     73    C      0
13      5     85    D      0
14      6     56    X     52
15      7     99    E      0
16      8      4    F      0
17      9     74    G      0
```

Intermediate:

```
# get the value of the row following the previous X
df['ColA'].shift(-1)[m].shift()

2         NaN
5     11111.0
11        7.0
14        4.0
Name: ColA, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, worked. Will implement on larger datatset and revert if any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Might this code be useful for your solution? I also attached the output ss so that you have a clear idea about the working.

```
 import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ColA': [1, 2, 3, 11111, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'ColB': [11, 5, 22, 66, 4, 33333, 45, 91, 78, 10, 17, 55, 73, 85, 56, 99, 4, 74],
    'ColC': ['A', 'B', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'G']
})

# Find the indices of the first and last occurrence of 'X' in ColC
first_appear = df['ColC'].eq('X').idxmax()
last_appear = df['ColC'].eq('X')[::-1].idxmax()
final_df = df.loc[first_appear+1:last_appear]
final_df['ColD'] = final_df['ColB'] - final_df['ColA']
print(final_df)
```

[image: Output]